# code::blocks animated/automated single step source

Tags: c, console, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks 16 in Win7 (SP1 32bit) to debug a C console program. (Multiple monitors, the C::B with source in one monitor, the console prog in another.)

Is there a way I can get C::B to single step through my code, moving the highlighted source line, automatically advancing to the next instruction without me clicking the "next line" button?

I have some complex irritations in functions and one is slowing the program down, and it would be nice to see which instruction is taking so much time.

Thanks, Mark.

Edit: More details.

When single stepping code, I can click the "Next Line" icon. The debugger will execute the current line, then stop at the next line (as expected.)

I'd like an "Animate" button. Where it is *like* clicking the Next Line Icon (the debugger executes the current line and stops at the next line) then have the editor highlight the (now current) 'next line' and then automatically (after some configurable time) move to the next line again. This should continue till I press some kind of "animate stop" button (or Esc or something.)

Comment: post a [mcve] and please clarify exactly what your trying to perform

Comment: Since I don't know if this feature even exists, I can't post an example. Let me edit the question and, maybe, add further details.